# how to get details of current user in twitter

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am working on a PHP application for which I want to get some information about current twitter user using OAuth .

Information like

1. Screen name
2. Date of birth
3. E-mail id
   4 .Time zone etc.

These things I have completed

1. Created a  twitter App.
2. Obtained oauth_token and oauth_verifier by using a login url  using call back.

I require an API request Syntax like

```
$user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

Which will give the above details, basically equivalent in Facebook to

```
$this->facebook->api('/me');
```

Thanks.

Comment: What OAuth library did you use?

Comment: The Twitter API documentation shows what you can retrieve about a user, at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show. You can get #1 and #4 from your list.

Comment: I have used TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2.

Comment: @jcmeloni Thanks .this contains all the info i want I will go through  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email addresses are not available. You could get more datas with this

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

with this query you are going to get all this datas :

```
 {
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "e0ff92",
  "name": "Twitter API",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "87bc44",
  "profile_background_tile": false,
  "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
  "profile_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/689684365/api_normal.png",
  "location": "San Francisco, CA",
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "id_str": "6253282",
  "profile_link_color": "0000ff",
  "is_translator": false,
  "contributors_enabled": true,
  "url": "http://dev.twitter.com",
  "favourites_count": 15,
  "utc_offset": -28800,
  "id": 6253282,
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "listed_count": 6868,
  "profile_text_color": "000000",
  "protected": false,
  ...
```

and more information about email in twitter forums: 
 https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1737

what I would do would be to redirect the user after Twitter login to small form if the user don't have a email in your db.

Comment: .Thanks so much.E-mail address is required to me as I am using it for login form.Any way we can find that ?

Comment: what I would do would be to redirect the user after Twitter login to small form if the user don't have a email in your db.

Comment: Sure I will do the same .Require the user to fill the form. manually thanks